# Imacros - Replace or delete all the apostraphies in a string of text

Tags: replace, eval, imacros

**Imacros Eval function to replace "'" with ""**

or just to delete all the ' in a string of text.

ive tried this but i cant get it to work with apostrophes

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:after_title EXTRACT=TXT    
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var extr2=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; extr2.replace(\"'\",\"\"); ")
```

After doing some reading i tried this, get an error

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:after_title EXTRACT=TXT    
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var extr2=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; extr2.replace(\'/g\,\"GHF\"); ")
```

I really hope some one can help, its really doing my head in

Answer (score 2):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:after_title EXTRACT=TXT    
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var extr2=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; extr2.replace(/'/g,''); ")
```

Can you try this and let us know if it worked?